# Variations of struct definitions in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, syntax

I have built a struct in two ways, see below (Fig. A & Fig. B). In my .c file I access the struct like so (Fig. C).

Can someone please explain why Figure A makes a compiler error when accessed by Fig. C. Also, why Figure B doesn't cause a compiler error when accessed using Fig. C? Fig.

I can appreciate the syntax, if the struct is being used inside itself, the name needs to be in two places, top and bottom of struct.

Is it related to a 'forward reference' of sorts for the compiler? A good explanation would be appreciated.

```
//Fig. A
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t* block_address;
    struct mem_table_entry_t* next_entry_ptr; 

}mem_table_entry_t;

typedef struct
{
    mem_table_entry_t two_kib[8];

}mem_table_t;
```

and

```
//Fig. B
typedef struct mem_table_entry_t
{
    uint32_t* block_address;
    struct mem_table_entry_t* next_entry_ptr; 

}mem_table_entry_t;

typedef struct
{
    mem_table_entry_t two_kib[8];

}mem_table_t;
```

...

```
//Fig. C
memory_table.two_kib[block].next_entry_ptr = &memory_table.two_kib[block+1];
```

Comment: are you sure snippet B compiles?

Comment: Give the compiler error, please!

Comment: I suspect the compilers feels that in `typedef struct T1 {...}  T2;` the `struct T1` and the `T2`  are not the same, even if `T1` and `T2` are replaced by `T0`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - The compiler error with Fig.A is: 
#515 a value of type "mem_table_entry_t *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "struct mem_table_entry_t *"

Comment: @SouravGhosh - Yes, snippet B compiles and does what I want. Is there something wrong/illegal with it?

Comment: Snipped B has a stray semicolon in the first typedef line.

Comment: @Darrell so, you meant to say. `typedef struct mem_table_entry_t;{...` is a valid C syntax? My whole life is a lie..... :(

Comment: Ok...yes, there is a typo there (local to this post only). Apologies. The questions are still valid, despite the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In snippet A, there is no `struct mem_table_entry_t` defined [yet] in the `struct` tag namespace. So you cannot refer to it as in `struct mem_table_entry_t* next_entry_ptr;`.

Your snippet B is correct.

Note also that the `typedef` namespace is distinct from the `struct` tag namespace. This means the the following are not compatible:

```
mem_table_entry_t two_kib1[8];
struct mem_table_entry_t two_kib2[8];
```

Comment: I'll be honest, I still don't know the difference between 'typedef struct' and just 'struct'.

Comment: `typedef...t_newtype` declares `t_newtype` to be a new type defined as what is the `...`. `struct {...} a` declares a variable `a` that is a structure.

Comment: @Darrel: Just strike out `typedef` from your mind and be happy. It is not necessary at all to use it in any case. To define a struct just do `struct S {...};` and do define a variable of it do `struct S s;`.